# checking if any element in a list starts with any of a number of prefixes in Python?

Tags: python, string, numpy

I'm trying to check if any of a number of string `targets` starts with one of any number of given `prefixes`, e.g.:

```
prefixes = ["a", "b", "c"]
targets = ["abar", "xbar"]
```

then check if any element of `targets` has a prefix that is in `prefixes` (and find those elements of `targets` along with the first prefix they matched). Here `"abar"` is the only element that fits. My own version is:

```
for t in target:
  if any(map(lambda x: t.startswith(x), prefixes)):
    print t
```

is there a better/shorter/faster way using plain Python or numpy?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? If you're using Python 2, change that `map` to a generator. The `map` runs through your entire list needlessly.

Comment: @Blender: how would you change it to a generator?

Comment: @user248237 -- One easy way is to just change `map` to `itertools.imap`.  The other is to use a generator expression (which looks remarkably similar to a list-comp):  `(t.startswith(x) for x in prefixes)`

Comment: better yet use `any(t.startswith(x) for x in prefixes)` It's faster and works the same in Python2 or Python3

Comment: When you hear "prefix", you should think "[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)"

Comment: Thanks but the advantage of the map over `any(t.startswith(x) for x in prefixes)` is that you get an array of `True/False` and you can tell which of the prefixes your target matches. Plain `any` will not reveal which prefix it matched

Comment: @user248237: huh?  `any(map(lambda x: t.startswith(x), prefixes))` won't tell you which prefix it matched either.

Comment: @DSM: it will if you parse `map(lambda x: t.startswith(x), prefixes)` - my point is that it has that info. You can pass the info to `any` or you can look for the index of the first `True` element, and that's the first prefix that matches.

Comment: So will `next((p for p in prefixes if t.startswith(p)), None)`, which would short-circuit to boot, but that wasn't what your question described and wasn't the behaviour of your example code, invalidating my answer, unfortunately.

Comment: DSM: sorry my question wasn't clear I updated that requirement I would have accepted your answer given the unclarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the matches just use this list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> matches = [(t,p) for t,p in product(targets,prefixes) if t.startswith(p)]
>>> print(matches)
[('abar', 'a'), ('cbar', 'c')]
```

If you just want the first one, use next with the list comprehension as a generator expression. This will short-circuit if you just want to determine if any match exists.

```
>>> nextmatch = next(((t,p) for t,p in product(targets,prefixes) if t.startswith(p)), None)
>>> print(nextmatch)
[('abar', 'a')]
```

Answer (score 2):

same as @DSM

you can use **filter**

```
>>> prefixes = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> targets = ["abar", "xbar"]
>>> filter(lambda t: t.startswith(prefixes), targets)
['abar']
```

Answer (score 1):

I used lists in the result to store the prefix since there might be more than one match

```
>>> prefixes = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> targets = ["abar", "xbar"]
>>> result = {t:[p for p in prefixes if t.startswith(p)] for t in targets}
>>> result
{'abar': ['a'], 'xbar': []}
```

If you need to filter the empty lists

```
>>> result = {k:v for k,v in result.items() if v}
>>> result
{'abar': ['a']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions? 
[Re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)
[Python's regular expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)

Comment: Highly unnecessary for constant string prefixes, and would be quite a bit slower than `.startswith`.

Comment: Don't jump to re's when string methods like `startswith` or `endswith` will do - this ain't Perl!